# php Dollar amount Regular Expression

Tags: php, regex

I am have completed javascript validation of a form using Regular Expressions and am now working on redundant verification server-side using PHP.

I have copied this regular expression from my jscript code that finds dollar values, and reformed it to a PHP friendly format:

```
/\$?((\d{1,3}(,\d{3})*)|(\d+))(\.\d{2})?$/
```

Specifically:

```
if (preg_match("/\$?((\d{1,3}(,\d{3})*)|(\d+))(\.\d{2})?$/", $_POST["cost"])){}
```

While the expression works great in javascript I get :

```
Warning: preg_match() [function.preg-match]: Compilation failed: nothing to repeat at offset 1
```

when I run it in PHP.  Anyone have a clue why this error is coming up?

Comment: Was missing escaping the $ as a couple replies point out below

\\\$    or use single quotes to enclose the regex, thanks guys!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

you have to double escape the $.

`if (preg_match("/\\\$?((\d{1,3}(,\d{3})*)|(\d+))(\.\d{2})?$/", $_POST["cost"])){}`

just putting \$ will have php escape the $ from starting a variable. You also have to add another escaped \ (\\) in front. Or you could just use single quotes so php doesn't interpret the $ as the start of a variable.

Comment: Works great, I hate swapping languages and forgetting all of the escaped characters =(.  Thanks!

Comment: This will fail to match a number such as 2000 (will give 200).

Comment: @afilina if it does, that is the fault of the original post as I just showed them how to fix their expression to work in php.

Answer (score 1):

From PHP documentation:

> Do not use [preg_match()](http://dk.php.net/manual/en/function.preg-match.php) if you
>   only want to check if one string is
>   contained in another string. Use
>   [strpos()](http://dk.php.net/manual/en/function.strpos.php)  or [strstr()](http://dk.php.net/manual/en/function.strstr.php)  instead as they
>   will be faster.

Comment: How is that relevant?  The OP is doing a regex match, and the `preg_*` functions are how you do that.

Comment: Yeah, I'm testing a format not a string or I would avoid regex like the plague.

Answer (score 1):

Try this:

```
if (preg_match('/\$?((\d{1,3}(,\d{3})*)|(\d+))(\.\d{2})?$/', $_POST["cost"])){}
```

The dollar sign between " are considered as the start of a variable. Compare with these two code snippets:

1:

```
$var = "hello";
echo "$var world";
```

2:

```
$var = "hello";
echo '$var world';
```